# How to clear a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm still a noob to Swing classes and I wanted to clear the screen after the user activates a button.

```
    JButton tes=new JButton("TEST");
    tes.setBounds(550, 375, 200, 75);
    tes.setFocusable(false);
    tes.setFont(new Font("comic sans",Font.PLAIN,20));
    tes.setBackground(Color.white);
    tes.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2, true));
    tes.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                test('T');
            }
            catch(IOException e1) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e1);
            }
        }
    });

    f.add(tit);f.add(sub);
    f.add(pr);f.add(tes);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

I have used the following and it didn't really do anything.

```
removeAll()
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: what do you mean, you want to clear the screen?

Comment: So you want to remove all components from your frame? (and then what?) Anyways, please provide a [mre] of your problem, because we currently cannot tell where your approach fails, since you did not provide enough information.

Comment: If what I suspect you want is correct (and I'm not sure, post a MRE & explain a bit more like what comes next?), then I'd use a `CardLayout` and on 'clear screen', flip to an empty `JPanel`. As clear as you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
frame.repaint();
```

you should use it this way

Comment: You probably need to `revalidate` the `contentPane` before you `repaint` (just to be sure), but I would argue that something `CardLayout` might be a better choice

Comment: Tysm it worked.